# Optimising specific Query with ACF meta objects

Tags: wp-query, query, query-posts

Is there any way I can improve the following query without touching the server, as it's taking around 5-6 seconds to execute, the SQL is outputing as:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (483,481,479)
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (8) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'people'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date_of_silk' )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC
```

The PHP to output this query is as follows:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'post_type' => 'people', 'tax_query' => array( array('taxonomy' => 'level', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $termslug)), 'meta_key' => 'date_of_silk', 'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post__not_in' => $exclude_joined);
query_posts($args); while(have_posts()): the_post();
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How often or under what conditions do the results of that query change? A simple fix is to save the results in an option on the back end whenever the data changes, so your front end just has to do a quick option load instead of a complex query.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: there are hooks for every action you do on the admin side, `save_post`, `delete_post`, `publish_post`. you would hook a function to those to update the contents of your option when a post from your cpt is added/published/deleted.